is it necessary to use `\fp_eval:n`?
Is it necessary to use \fp_eval:n in \tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } { \fp_eval:n {#2} } in the module below ?  I found \tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }  {#2} works fine without \fp_eval:n.

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {
  \keyval_parse:NNn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n \xcn_eqdef_def:nn {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n
 {
  \msg_error:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value } {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_def:nn
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist } {#1}
   }
   {
    \tl_new:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   }
  \tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } { \fp_eval:n {#2} }
%\tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } {#2} 
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value }
 { Missing~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
 { You~must~supply~a~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
\msg_new:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist }
 { Overriding~value~for~the~variable~#1 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\eqdef{aa=11,bb = 12+21 , cc= 33,dd=44,ff,aa=13}

\begin{document}

$\fpeval{\usevar{aa}+\usevar{bb}-\usevar{cc}*\usevar{dd}}$

$\fpeval{13+12+21-33*44}$

\end{document}


What is the expected output of \eqdef{aa=1+1}\usevar{aa}?

it is supposed to be 2

Then the answer is yes.

you mean using \fp_eval:n is necessary ?

Yes, did you try to type only \eqdef{aa=1+1}\usevar{aa} in the document body without using \fp_eval:n?

I didn't . I'll test it later.

In the examples you used \fpeval outside the definition of \eqdef, so you did not notice the problem...

It isn't necessary to use expl3 at all.

thanks @UdiFogiel for pointing out my problem.

If you omit the expansion and \fp_eval:n what you're storing is the direct input, so fail=1+2 will be 1+2, and if you then use that in a calculation (without adding parenthesis) you'll get an unexpected result.
Consider the following minimal example in which I removed the \fp_eval:n and get a wrong result:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\eqdef}{m}
 {
  \keyval_parse:NNn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n \xcn_eqdef_def:nn {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_invalid:n
 {
  \msg_error:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value } {#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_eqdef_def:nn
 {
  \tl_if_exist:cTF { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   {
    \msg_warning:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist } {#1}
   }
   {
    \tl_new:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl }
   }
  \tl_gset:cn { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } {#2}
%\tl_gset:ce { g_xcn_eqdef_#1_tl } {#2} 
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/eqdef } { missing-value }
 { Missing~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
 { You~must~supply~a~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
\msg_new:nnn { xcn/eqdef } { var-exist }
 { Overriding~value~for~the~variable~#1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\eqdef{fail=2+1}

\begin{document}

$\fpeval{\usevar{fail}*2} \neq 6$ 

\end{document}



thanks@Skillmon If I don't omit the expansion , will there be unexpected result ?

If you put \fp_eval:n inside but omit the expansion things should work out correctly, but are slower since \fp_eval:n is executed on each usage (might turn out to be faster if you need only a few of the defined variables and only once or twice).

@xcn if you omit \fp_eval:n, the expansion of 1+1 is 1+1, so if you expect it to be 2, you will get an unexpected result. there's no reason for TeX to do arithmetic unless you tell it to.

thanks a lot @cfr you're right . Since there in a command \NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{O{15}m}  {\fpeval{round( \tl_use:c { g_xcn_eqdef_#2_tl },#1)}  } in my local module. that's why I get right answer.
